# External javascript File Problem

Tags: javascript

Good day!

Why is it that when I make the following javascript code external, some codes doesn't work

```
<form name="Keypad" action="">
</form>


                        var FKeyPad = document.Keypad; // DOESN'T WORK ANYMORE
                        var Accumulate = 0;
                        var FlagNewNum = false;
                        var PendingOp = "";
                        function NumPressed (Num) {
                            if (FlagNewNum) {
                                FKeyPad.ReadOut.value  = Num;
                                FlagNewNum = false;
                            }
                            else {
                                if (FKeyPad.ReadOut.value == "0")
                                    FKeyPad.ReadOut.value = Num;
                                else
                                    FKeyPad.ReadOut.value += Num;
                            }
                        }
```

How can I make it work?

Thank you,

Comment: `document.Keypad`? what's your dependency (js library)?

Comment: I'm calling the FORM I've created....

Comment: opps. my bad :) and if you are mentioning to this article http://javascript.internet.com/math-related/advanced.html , would say lousy code. dont copy :)

Comment: if using jquery `$(function (){...code...})` else onload event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your external JS file just before `</body>` tag and should work.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with the code being external, it's all about when the code is executed.

You have to execute the code after the element has been created. You can put the script tag below the element in the code, or you can put the code in the handler for the `window.onload` event to make it run after the page has loaded:

```
window.onload = function() {
  // your code here
};
```

Comment: Where would i put the window.onload?

Comment: in my javascript external file or in my hmtl? Thank you

Comment: I would suggest using a library like Mootools or something. It will make life easier.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any sources which mention document.Keypad. I don't think it's supported by normal browsers.